# Rotating animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, rotation

I'm rotating an arrow by 45 degrees. When an animation ends, the arrow returns to its original state (0 degrees). I need that the arrow doesn't return to original state and it will be rotate by 45 degrees at the end of animation.

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotationShort = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotationShort.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotationShort.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI/28*4.7];
fullRotationShort.duration = 1.0f;
fullRotationShort.repeatCount = 1;
[imgViewArrowShort.layer addAnimation:fullRotationShort forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property:

```
fullRotationShort.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
fullRotationShort.cumulative = YES;
   fullRotationShort.removedOnCompletion=NO;
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your arrow is a `UIImageView` named `arrow`.
You really don't need such complicated CAAnimations for this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ 
    arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.25 * M_PI);
}];
```

Comment: Saved my day :) Thanks for such simple and elegant solution.